# How to get a system date change notification in .NET core on linux?

Tags: events, .net-core, .net-standard, systemevent

I'm trying to get a notification event in .NET core/Standard (as I need to do plan  future actions). I'm porting a piece of existing .NET4.5x code to .NET core 2.2 or .NETStandard2.

Originally I was using:

```
SystemEvents.TimeChanged += SystemEvents_TimeChanged; //my handler
```

But in .NETCore or .NETStandard, [this is not implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28007).

What is the most elegant way to overcome that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so finally I did it that way (pseudo code):

```
public TimeSpan CheckInterval { get; private set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
public TimeSpan MaxAllowedDeviation { get; private set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

private async Task CheckTimeUpdate()
{
    while (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
    {
        DateTimeOffset beforeTimer = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        await Task.Delay(CheckInterval, cancelToken);

        DateTimeOffset afterTimer = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        if ((afterTimer.UtcDateTime - beforeTimer.UtcDateTime).Duration() > MaxAllowedDeviation + CheckInterval)
        {
            //raises the event
            TimeChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

But this only works for manual time change, not for daylight saving nor time zone updates!!